# What is different Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry and Window 8? Specifically .NET

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, embedded, windows-embedded

My project using .NET and can run with XP,WIN7,WIN8. But maybe we made we own hardware on feature. So I need to know Windows Embedded 8 system.

But I'm not found some information about what's different Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry and normal windows OS on PC. because my project using C#,C++ build on X86 SYSTEM.

and the another question is : How I buy it ? I go to microsoft website, maybe my English not very well , so I don't know Those steps for buy. Microsoft will do for us to generate the hardware if we buy it? Microsoft limits the number you buy it? How much is it?

thank you very much.

> by the way: Is the windows embedded 8 has Directshow for handle the video and music?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry is a combination of a normal Windows 8.1 build plus the addition of additional Embedded features you can enable during build/post build.  From an application compatibility standpoint it is identical to Windows 8.1.

This is in sharp contrast to Windows Embedded Standard 7/8, where you can omit components from the final build and impact application compatibility pretty easily in a negative fashion.

You can evaluate it with MSDN.  I think you have to buy it from one of a few companies, I would contact one of the listed partners: 
https://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/partners.aspx#none

Answer (score 0):

Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry has limitations of hardware,it do not support more than 4gb memory(you can hack bcd to extend this),and
do not support cpu more then 4 processers(including hyper thread virtual CPUs).

except these limitations ,it is quiet the same as windows 8.1 pro.

Comment: Are you sure that it has this limitations? Because I saw that it's the same W8.1 except store apps.

Comment: I do have an i7 laptop which i have tried to install windows embedded 8.1,it only recognise  4gb memory and only 4threads

Comment: @z8r0 Is that the 32bit or the 64bit version of Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro? Just wanted to confirm because if you are needing more than 4GB of RAM (e.g. 8GB or 16GB of RAM) on Windows system, a 64bit version is generally better supported (in terms of RAM utilization)..

Comment: @Trent 64bit version